# How merge expressions in custom directives Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive, angularjs-templates

I break my head try to resolve this problem. Suppose that I have this custom directive:

```
app.directive("selectInput",function($compile){
return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: 'js/angular-app/test.html',
    scope: {                
        formName:'=',
        inputName:"=",
        nameInput: "@",
        ngModel: "=",
    },
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {   
        ...             
    },
}});
```

Here my templateurl test.html

```
<div
class="form-group"
ng-class="{'has-error has-feedback': formName.inputName.$invalid}"> 
<input type="text" name="{{nameInput}}" ng-model="ngModel"/></div>
```

And the call

```
<form name="form" class="simple-form" novalidate>
<select-input 
    form-name="form"                       
    input-name="fClase"            
    name-input="fClase"
    ng-model="inputmodel">
</select-input></form>
```

The problem is in test.html template, the expression `formName.inputName.$invalid` not work, I try `{{formName}}.{{inputName}}.$invalid` and nothing, also I try change the params in directive definition for `&, @ ... =?`.

I have not been able to merge this expressions, I appreciate any help.

**Update, fix the problem (Thanks to Joe Enzminger):**

At the end I change the directive by this:

```
app.directive("selectInput",function($compile){
return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: 'js/angular-app/test.html',
    scope: {           
        inputName: "@",
        ngModel: "=",
    },
    require: ["^form"],
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {  
        scope.form = ctrl[0]; 
        ...             
    },
}});
```

Note the form attr as ctrl.

The template test.html

```
<div
class="form-group"
ng-class="{'has-error has-feedback': form[inputName].$invalid}"> 
<input type="text" name="{{nameInput}}" ng-model="ngModel"/></div>
```

Here change `formName.inputName.$invalid` by `form[inputName].$invalid`

And finally the call

```
<form name="form" class="simple-form" novalidate>
<select-input        
    input-name="fClase"   
    ng-model="inputmodel">
</select-input></form>
```

I hopefully useful

Comment: Use something other than ng-model as the name of your model (ng-model is going to get confused with the angular ng-model directive (use something like "model-name" instead.  You can then use formName[modelName].$invalid in your ng-class expression.  However, take a look at my answer below for an alternative implementation that is a little cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative implementation that might clarify how things actually work.

The changes:

Don't inject $compile (you don't use it)

No transclude: true (you aren't using transclusion)

scope: {} - we create an empty isolate scope so that our template will work and we can isolate the directive scope from the parent scope.

require: ["ngModel", "^form"] - we want to require ngModel on the element and require that the element is embedded in a form.  These will be delivered to the link functions ctrl parameter.

```
<div
class="form-group"
ng-class="{'has-error has-feedback': form[model.$name].$invalid}"> 
<input type="text" ng-model="model.$modelValue"/></div>

<form name="form" class="simple-form" novalidate>
<select-input 
    ng-model="inputmodel">
</select-input></form>

app.directive("selectInput",function(){
return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: 'js/angular-app/test.html',
    scope: {},
    replace: true,
    require: ["ngModel", "^form"],
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {  
        //give our directive scope access to the model and form controllers
        $scope.model = ctrl[0];
        $scope.form = ctrl[1];          
    },
}});
```